# Yii - How to Show Value of Array in CGridView?

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem how to show value of array in CGridView?
I have this code in /user/admin.php

```
array(
    'type'=>'raw',
    'name'=>'jabatan',
    'header'=>'Jabatan',
    'filter'=>array('0'=>'Kepala Subdirektorat','1'=>'Kepala Seksi','2'=>'Staf'),
    'value'=>$data->jabatan
),
```

I have set `'value'=>$data->value`

but it shows the index of array, ex. '1'. I wanted to show the value of array, ex. 'Staf'.

So, how to show its value? Anybody can help me fix this? Thanks a lot

Comment: What result are you expecting by setting a array to the value?

Comment: I expect the value of array not the index of array. I have set $data->jabatan to fix prior error

Comment: As the array seems to be hard-coded and not being fetched from some database table, create a static function in that model and pass the `$data->jabatan` to it. Eg: `'value' => MODEL_NAME::staticFuncName($data->jabatan)` and return the required value from that function.

Comment: thanks @KunalDethe, I have tried by myself and found a problem solved

Answer (score 2):

Oh thanks a lot to @Kunal Dethe for his advice, I've solved it

I just create a function on model User.php

```
public function getNama_jabatan() {
    $listjabatan = array('0'=>'Kepala Subdirektorat', '1'=>'Kepala Seksi', '2'=>'Staf');
    $namajabatan = $listjabatan[$this->jabatan];
    return $namajabatan;
}
```

then, I call the function on /user/admin.php `'value'=>'$data->nama_jabatan'`

Thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 1):

In Model Class -

```
public static function getJabatanName($jabatan == null) {
    $value = '';

    if($jabatan) {
        if($jabatan == 0)
            $value = 'Kepala Subdirektorat';
        elseif($jabatan == 1)
            $value = 'Kepala Seksi';
        elseif($jabatan == 2)
            $value = 'Staf';
    }
    return $value;
}
```

And in admin.php -

```
array(
    'type'=>'raw',
    'name'=>'jabatan',
    'header'=>'Jabatan',
    'filter'=>array('0'=>'Kepala Subdirektorat','1'=>'Kepala Seksi','2'=>'Staf'),
    'value'=>MODEL_NAME::getJabatanName($data->jabatan)
),
```